# Bitbake how to use function from another file

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have 2 bitbake recipes with function `do_install_prepend()`. The point is that 90% of body of this function is similar in both recipes. I would like to do something like:

1. Create new file
2. Add common variables to the file
3. Create new function inside the file which contains the reusable part.
4. Use `require` inside the recipes.

So it looks pretty easy. I did it all of those steps, but it doesn't seem to work. I need the function from new file to run BEFORE the `do_install_prepend`. Of course I'm using `require` before the definition of `do_install`. Unfortunately the `do_install` is running first and causes recipe to fail.
Tried the `addtask`, `addtask new_func before do install` but then I receive the error that `new_function` command not found.

Comment: perhaps show us what you've done?

Comment: I just want to call function from another file (it can be .inc, .txt whatever) before another function specified in my bitbake recipe.